# mongodb aggregation - unwind/group/project query combination

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have records in a collection of the following format.

```
//One parent record
{
    "_id" : "someDocID",
    "title" : "some title",
    "analytics" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "analyticsID1", 
                   "timeSpent" : [
                            {
                                    "time" : 14,
                                    "pageNo" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : 4,
                                    "pageNo" : 2
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : 3,
                                    "pageNo" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : 1,
                                    "pageNo" : 2
                            }
                    ]                       

            },
            {                        
                    "_id" : "analyticsID2",                        
                    "timeSpent" : [
                            {
                                    "time" : 12,
                                    "pageNo" : 10
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : 15,
                                    "pageNo" : 11
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : 26,
                                    "pageNo" : 12
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : 13,
                                    "pageNo" : 11
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : 17,
                                    "pageNo" : 10
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : 30,
                                    "pageNo" : 11
                            }
                    ]
            }
    ]               
}
```

The "pageNo" field contains repeated values. I need to group the pageNo field with adding their respective "time".

This is my required output. ( after "$unwind" operation on analytics )

```
//Two records after "$unwind" on analytics
{
    "_id" : "someDocID",
    "title" : "some title",
    "analytics" : {
                    "_id" : "analyticsID1", 
                    "timeSpent" : [
                            {
                                    "time" : 17,   //14+3
                                    "pageNo" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : 5,    //4+1
                                    "pageNo" : 2
                            }
                    ]
            }
}

{
    "_id" : "someDocID",
    "title" : "some title",
    "analytics" : {
                    "_id" : "analyticsID2", 
                    "timeSpent" : [
                            {
                                    "time" : 29,    //12+17
                                    "pageNo" : 10
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : 58,    //15+13+30
                                    "pageNo" : 11
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : 26,
                                    "pageNo" : 12
                            }                                
                    ]      
            }
}
```

I've tried various combinations of aggregate, group, unwind and project but still can't quite get there and would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What do you want to end with? Are you trying to sum "time" by "pageNo", or "time" by "pageNo" for each analytics ID?

Comment: I want to sum "time" by "pageNo".

Comment: I want something like this.
analyticsID1 -> { timeSpent : [ { time : 10, pageNo: 1 },..] },
analyticsID2 -> { timeSpent : [ { time : 20, pageNo: 1 },..] }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an aggregate I came up with to provide the output that you mentioned in your comment above.  As an FYI, the more elements you have in an array that needs to be unwound, the more memory usage you'll have, and it will take an exponentially amount of time based on array sizes.  I would highly recommend you structure your data differently if your arrays are not limited in length.

```
var aggregrate = [{
    $unwind: '$analytics'
}, {
    $unwind: '$analytics.timeSpent'
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            analytics_id: '$analytics._id',
            pageNo: '$analytics.timeSpent.pageNo'
        },
        title:{$first:'$title'},
        time: {
            $sum: '$analytics.timeSpent.time'
        },
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$_id.analytics_id',
        title:{$first:'$title'},
        timeSpent: {
            $push: {
                time: '$time',
                pageNo: '$_id.pageNo'
            }
        }
    }
}, ];
```

This Outputs:

```
[{
    "_id": "analyticsID1",
    "title" : "some title", 
    "timeSpent": [{
        "time": NumberInt(17),
        "pageNo": NumberInt(1)
    }, {
        "time": NumberInt(5),
        "pageNo": NumberInt(2)
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "analyticsID2",
     "title" : "some title", 
     "timeSpent": [{
        "time": NumberInt(26),
        "pageNo": NumberInt(12)
    }, {
        "time": NumberInt(29),
        "pageNo": NumberInt(10)
    }, {
        "time": NumberInt(58),
        "pageNo": NumberInt(11)
    }]
}]
```

Comment: This includes the title of each document in the output, and formats it in the way you seemed to be asking in your above comment.  If you want the output to be different, just let me know and I'll update the aggregate.

Comment: Thanks for crafting the solution. It worked great. 
I am considering your recommendation on structuring the data as 2nd stage of unwinding and then grouping is going to take a lot of memory and time.